# SQL Server 2008 R2: Timeout exception when updating a table with a guid primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, guid

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 which has a primary key of `Guid` type. After days of testing the database, now this table has 7000 rows.

I have a query which when the data is about 1000 records works, but now it does not.

The query is :

```
update Ticket 
set AlphaCode = "Hi" 
where TicketId = 'fe0b840d-5688-4f38-a1fe-46eb6ff04296'
```

The datatype of the `AlphaCode` column is `nvarchar(1024)`.

The previous query sometimes runs in about 10 seconds! But many times it fails with

> *Timeout exception*

The interesting thing is that the following query returns the record in less than a sec:

```
select * 
from Ticket 
where TicketId = 'fe0b840d-5688-4f38-a1fe-46eb6ff04296'
```

This means that the DBMS engine has no difficulty finding my record but the problem lays under the updating operation.

Comment: Maybe you have a bad index on that table that has to be repaired.

Comment: is primary key clustered index and how the guid generated and do you envisage the table to grow beyond 10k rows? defrag the table and try it might help.

Comment: Are there triggers on the Ticket table? They are invoked in update (and may cause some locks) and not in select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use Guids for clustered keys. If you find out how a clustered key works and how it arranges data on disk then you would realise how expensive updates and deletes are on those tables.

See other question here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/guid-as-primary-key-best-practices).