# Primary Key type in Cloud Share Database web app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i'm building a cloud web app with asp mvc and mssql. Clients will share the same database.
I still havent decided what type my primary key will be. Should i use GUID or Bigint?
with bigint, i'm worried about scalabilty. with GUID, i'm afraid of performance.
What is the best practice here? What big cloud website like stackoverflow use as primary key?
Please shed me some light.

Thanks,

Reynaldi

Answer (score 0):

I would use Guids. You don't want sequential ID's when dealing with backups and restore.

Answer (score 0):

I would use INT as the performance is better than any other datatype the best Datatype you can have for your Primary key. You can get more then 2 billion records using INT and if you get to a point where you need more then 2 billion Primary keys in one table you should consider Table Partitioning. But using GUID or BIGINT will have the performance penalty anyway even if you have only few thousand records in your table. INT is a 4 byte datatype and GUID is a 16-byte datatype, So you could say INT x 4 Memory is required to store the GUID Column and Plus the performance penalty. Here is a very details answer by marc_s [Detailed Comparison of GUID Vs Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega)

Answer (score 0):

Both have their good and bad. The real question is not about what datatype to use, but rather "in what way is the data going to be used"?

For example, if you are going to use the data in a manner where you will have millions of reads, and you require the data in the inserted order, and it makes sense to 'sort' the data in the manner that it was inserted, then perhaps an IDENTITY INT column will do. No need for BIGINT really, you can even seed your INT column with -2 billion and have potentially 4 billion records in there, and I doubt you will get there. You will not want to use int or bigint if you ever want to 'shard' or scale your table out. Especially when you use SQL Azure, which makes scaling out simple, you then would want to steer more in the direction of using a GUID.

Sure with a GUID it is not 'sorted' in the table in inserted order, but it definitely makes sense to use if you plan to scale out, or even use to join tables in other databases.

If you are going to do massive batch inserts, say 10,000 rows plus per batch, then something like an INT will be better suited, since it will avoid page splits, or keep it to a minimum rather. However, if the batch inserts happens during quiet hours, this is not an issue.

Again, SQL Server indexes are brilliant, and if you can get a proper index for your table, there is no need not to use either of them.

Indexes is a whole other kettle of fish, but since it was not part of the question, I will not attempt to answer it here, but I would spend a bit of time understanding the impact of too many/little or the wrong indexes on a table, if I were you.

Really the answer to your question is not as simple as GUID or INT/BIGINT, but rather a holistic view and understanding of your application, its usage, and how and when your table will be used. Only then can you make a decision that will best suit your table.

I hope this helps.