# Should I use Guid or Int as Primary Key (Entity Framework 6)

Tags: c#, database-design, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, guid

I know this question is asked alot, but I still can't decide which one is better for me.

In my system I have a table of Emails.

New emails are created often, the ones that exist are deleted often, there is alot of movement in that table - records change very often.

This table will contain at max a few thousands of records

Another important fact is that I will need to synchronize the emails accross multiple database instances, to keep indication about email's status - Recieved/Read, etc..

Guid promises uniqueness.
Int is a bit more of a headache but each instance of the database has a unique prefix number (location identifier), so by using it manually generated unique Int keys can be generated without a problem.

Guids are less comfortable to work with, consumes more memory, look bad in clients eyes, and in each insert action EF needs to search for the right place to put the entity according to the generated Guid.

The only advantage I see for using Guid is the comfortable way to synchronize between entities across different instances of the tables.

What kind of key would you use for the table I have? Any suggestions?

If I missed any information tell me,

Thanks!

Comment: From RELATED: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11938044/1070452

Comment: I'm not a database expert, I don't understand some parts that are described in that question. I wanted to hear what is prefered for this case without going in depth to database terms