# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework 7 RC1, I have these entities:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public List<BookPage> Pages { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
} 

public class BookPage
{
    [Key]
    public string BookPageId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    [Key]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

*ApplicationDbContext.cs* is default, with `public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }`

When I'm trying to insert new Book, like this

```
var book = new Book()
{
    BookId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Pages = new List<BookPage>()
    {
        new BookPage()
        {
            BookPageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Number = 1
        }
    },
    Author = new Author()
    {
        AuthorId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        FullName = "Forexample"
    },
    Text = "new book"
};
dbContext.Books.Add(book);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

It throws exception:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Book_Author_AuthorAuthorId".

What's the problem with this simple insert? I don't want manually add BookPage and Author, it's Entity Framework job.

Comment: the record already exists may be.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh no, database is empty

Comment: If your ids are Guids why are use using `string`?  Also I'm pretty sure you have to `dbContext.BookPages.Add` the `BookPage`s and the same with the new `Author`.

Comment: Try first adding BookPage and Author in respective table and then use same Guid in Book's BookPage and Author.

Comment: @PKV this is simple example, but if I'll have more entities, what should I do with them? Add hundred if entities to database manually?

Comment: Can you provides us the code of the `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ApplicationDbContext` class you have to add a `DbSet` for the `Author` class  and for the `BookPage` class :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BookPage> BookPages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

So that you can rewrite your code like that :

```
var author = dbContext.Authors.Add(new Author()
{
    AuthorId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    FullName = "Forexample"
}).Entity;

var page = dbContext.BookPages.Add(new BookPage()
{
    BookPageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Number = 1
}).Entity;


var book = new Book.Book()
{
    BookId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    Pages = new List<BookPage>(),
    Text = "new book"
};
book.Pages.Add(page);
book.Author = author ;
dbContext.Books.Add(book);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Anyway **you shouldn't use `Guid` as a primary key** (in fact as a clustered index), this is a bad practice using SQL Server.

You can have a look at this post for more information :

- [What are the best practices for using a GUID as a primary key, specifically regarding performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega)

An alternative is to use an identity column as the primary key and add a other column (which will contain the unique id) with a unique constraint so that your model could look like that :

```
public class Author
{
    public Author()
    {
        AuthorUid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorUid { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        BookUid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Pages = new List<BookPage>();
    }

    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Guid BookUid { get; set; }
    public List<BookPage> Pages { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class BookPage
{
    public BookPage()
    {
        BookPageUid = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public int BookPageId { get; set; }
    public Guid BookPageUid { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

In your `DbContext`, you can specify the unique constraints:

```
public class BookContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<BookPage> BookPages { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Author>().HasAlternateKey(a => a.AuthorUid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().HasAlternateKey(a => a.BookUid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookPage>().HasAlternateKey(a => a.BookPageUid);
    }
}
```

And add your new entities like that :

```
using (var dbContext = new BookContext())
{
    var author = dbContext.Authors.Add(new Author()
    {
        FullName = "Forexample"
    }).Entity;

    var page = dbContext.BookPages.Add(new BookPage()
    {
        Number = 1
    }).Entity;

    var book = new Book.Book()
    {
        Text = "new book"
    };

    book.Pages.Add(page);
    book.Author = author;

    dbContext.Books.Add(book);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? not to have to add it to the DbSet ?

Comment: yes, only create book, wiith bookpages and author inside, and then add to DbSet only book.

Comment: I don't think so because you need to attach the author and the bookpages to the EF context. But I am going to check this for you

Comment: Yes you need to tell EF explicitly which element you want to insert