# using guid as entity Id

Tags: guid, abp

I strongly used to use hilo algorithm for generating pk ids, and is really veryusefull also for readibility and fast for locating an entity.
Is not the same with GUID, and as i see many examples of abp are using it.
Any suggestion, about using GUID o HILO? (Despite the fact that guid is almost universe unique)

I feel that guid is too cumbersome for debugging

add an extra column with an id Integer, will it be too much?

Comment: ABP uses this class to generate GUIDs by default: https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.Guids/Volo/Abp/Guids/SequentialGuidGenerator.cs
You can use int for your entities, ABP doesn't force Guid.

Comment: I already know  I can use int with abp, but talking about real application and good practices. i think also is a good contribution to abp comunity.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega