# Is it bad practice to use unique id of DB row and setting it at html id attriburte?

Tags: html, database, security

To keep it simple, I'm creating a list of of items in React that are pulled from the DB. Part of this is that we can delete/add items to the list, which i also want to reflect in the DB.

On creation of the item, I am generating a unique id for it and storing in the DB, and then when the list is rendered, I'm setting it's generated unique id as the id attribute in the div. So, upon user selecting that item to be deleted, i can just reference the id attribute and map back to my DB for removal.

I'll also validate that the unique ID is coming in correct format/length before hitting the DB to prevent mysql injection.

for ex:

```
<div>

   <div id='UniqueIdOfItem1'
      Item 1
   </div>

   <div id='UniqueIdOfItem2'
      Item 2
   </div>

   <div id='UniqueIdOfItem3'
      Item 3
   </div>

</div
```

Is this a bad practice? And security risk? If so, what other options could go with?

Comment: Aside from the fact that this has exactly nothing to do with SQL injection... It's certainly *uncommon* to do this, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it.  As long as the IDs are unique, valid HTML `id` values, and don't overlap with existing `id` values in the DOM then there's no problem.  It's generally more common to use `data-*` attributes to hold data values instead, and control the HTML `id` attributes more explicitly.  But if your way works for your data then there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a bad practice, in the contrary it is a good practice as react requires a `.map`ped array to have unique identifiers.

However, the way you are suggesting is not really a *reacty* way.

In react it is not recommended to refer directly to HTML attributes but we can `handle` things a bit different. In react we can pass this unique identifier as a `key` on your mapped array and add a `handler` to the element.

For your example this could be similar to:

```
const MyReactComponent = () => {
  const [myData, setMyData] = useState()

  const handleItemSelect = useCallback((item) => {
    console.log("selected ", item)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(HTTP://my.api)
    .then(data => {
      setMyData(data)
    })
    .catch(console.warn)
  }, [])

  return (
   <div>
    {myData.map((item, index) => (
      <div key={item.id} onClick={event => handleItemSelect(item)}>
        item {index}
      </div>
    ))}
   </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Storing important or confidential information, such as unique identifiers, in HTML attributes like "id" presents a security hazard as it exposes potentially valuable data directly in the client-side markup. This can result in security vulnerabilities, as malicious users can manipulate or guess these values to gain unauthorized access or carry out unintended actions within your application. It is crucial to maintain sensitive data and data management operations on the server-side, where you can enforce proper authentication, authorization, and validation mechanisms to guarantee data integrity and safeguard against security risks.

Comment: If no unique identifier is exposed to the client, how will the client make a request to modify or delete a specific record?

Comment: Instead of exposing database IDs directly, the server can generate unique tokens or UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers) for each record. These tokens are then associated with the corresponding database records. When the client needs to modify or delete a specific record, it sends the unique token as part of the request. The server uses the token to look up the corresponding database record.

Comment: If this is done dynamically each time, how can a record be referenced again at a later time?  (E.g. bookmarking a specific record’s URL)  If this is done once and stored in the database permanently, how is storing and exposing a unique identifier somehow more or less secure than storing and exposing another unique identifier?  It sounds like a convoluted solution to a non-issue.

Comment: SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE uuid_column = 'your_uuid_value';
In this SQL query, replace your_table with the name of your table, uuid_column with the name of the column storing UUIDs, and 'your_uuid_value' with the specific UUID you want to reference.  You can also use GUID a great discussion to learn more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938044/what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-a-guid-as-a-primary-key-specifically-rega

Comment: So, your suggestion is that instead of using a unique identifier, the OP should use a unique identifier?  That’s not exactly productive.  It really just sounds like you’re parroting some unrelated advice you once received without knowing what it actually means.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Good luck :)

Comment: @AfaqAliShah makes a good point regarding this -  "SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE uuid_column = 'your_uuid_value';"

Comment: @David Above Query is what i was referring to for SQL Injection. But could this not be an issue at all? Where this is just an imaginary issue?  Is there really no way for SQL Injection from using UUID from Database as ID//Key/Data-* in HTML?

Comment: @Jyang: SQL injection has nothing to do with your HTML or with using unique identifiers to uniquely identify records.  SQL injection happens when you execute user-modifiable values as SQL code.  Which you of course shouldn’t do.  You’re mixing up very different things here.

Comment: @David Yes that totally makes sense. Now I'm also curious, because the UUID is floating around the HTML, couldn't the user just use the chrome inspect tool to overwrite the UUID in the JS file as SQL Code? Ex:  UUID = "1111" so SQL looks like:

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UUID = 1111

But with SQL Injection they could overwrite UUID as UUID = "1111 OR 1=1" which then becomes: 

SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserId = 1111 OR 1=1;

Maybe i'm still getting myself confused, but wouldn't this be SQL Injection also?

Comment: @Jyang: Yes, the user can do that.  No, this is not SQL injection.  SQL injection happens in the code where you interact with the database.  That code, which isn’t shown in the question, may or may not be vulnerable to injection.  We can’t know.  But even without injection, users can spoof any ID they want.  Your server-side logic should validate that the user is permitted to perform whatever action they’re trying to perform on whatever record they specify.  This has nothing to do with SQL injection, nor with HTML id values, nor with different kinds of unique identifiers.

Comment: @David Awesome that helps clarify alot of my questions!